# Javascript: Most effecient way to define variable to a function call, or if null to a variable?

Tags: javascript

Using ternary operator requires two calls to the function.

```
var colour = (tryAdventurousColour() != null) ? tryAdventurousColour() : 'black';
```

Possible to do it in 1 line?

EDIT: Fixed syntax
EDIT: Like this but better

var colour = (  (colour = tryAdventurousColour() ) != null ) ? colour : 'black';

Comment: That is incorrect syntax for a ternary expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use JavaScript's logical or operator:

```
var colour = tryAdventurousColour() || 'black';
```

Your function `tryAdventurousColour()` will be executed once. If it returns a "truthy" value then that `colour` variable will be assigned to that value, otherwise `colour` will be 'black'. This fits your scenario perfectly since `null` is a "falsy" value.

In more general terms, the expression `a || b` returns `a` if it can be converted to true (is "truthy"), otherwise it returns `b`. Note that non-zero numbers, non-empty strings and objects will all be converted to true. `null`, undefined, 0, "" will all be converted to false. (I'm sure somebody will correct me if I've left something out.)

Comment: Keep in mind that `tryAdventurousColour()` shouldn't return `0` as a valid color.

Comment: Ha! of course: and var colour = (tryAdventurousColour() != failValue) || 'black';

Comment: No, don't do `var colour = (tryAdventurousColour() != failValue) || 'black'` because that will return either `true` or 'black'. The != expression evaluates to true or false, not to a colour. @katspaugh - good point, but then 0 would be black anyway wouldn't it? Another option is to move the default processing into the function...

Comment: @nnnnnn Ah whoops I meant  colour = (colour =(tryAdventurousColour() != failValue)) || 'black' but thats just crazy.

Comment: Nope, that has the same problem because the expression in the innermost parentheses returns a boolean. colour still ends up as true or 'black'.

Answer (score -1):

```
 var colour = (tryAdventurousColour()) ? tryAdventurousColour() : 'black';
```

Comment: hhehe ok roger that. If no-one can beat that in a few horus I guess you'll get the answer